# how to create service out of command?

Tags: server, services

I installed influxdb on ubuntu 16 and for some reason when I try to write in the terminal `service influxd` it gives me `influxd: unrecognized service.`

if I type only influxd than the influxdb server is starting up, so the command influxd is up

```
 $ which influxd :
 $ /usr/bin/influxd
```

What I try to do is to make it act like service so I can start and stop it on demand, and make it autostart on boot

tried making a symbolic link to folder /etc/init.d not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by adding your call into `/etc/rc.local` so that files contents would look like this afterwards:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

Examples (use only one, you might need to try which one will work):

# option 1. direct call
/usr/bin/influxd
# option 2. call it from init.d but I'm not sure this will work in your case
/etc/init.d/influxd start

exit 0
```

With Ubuntu 16.04 LTS you could, as pointed out in the comments, as well have a look at [`systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) services. I wouldn't be able to explain it better as in the linked doc-sheet so i leave it as link only.

Comment: with ubuntu 16.04 i would have a look at systemd services, however

Comment: @mnagel Good point, will add that to the answer, I usually post answers based on the solution which comes to my mind first :)